# Trying to Play Civ 5 or Civ 6, but they are not loading

Tags: 16.04, steam

I'm trying to play Civ 5 and Civ 6 on my Chromebook. I installed Ubuntu Linux using Crouton. I am currently using Xenial Ubuntu. Every time I try to play Civ 5 it's icon pops up for half a second then disappears.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the system requirements and if I can fix it so I can play. Also, I'm a beginner with Linux so any *command-line* help to fix this problem will be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I doubt your machine is capable of doing this, especially CIV6

Comment: I did get Civ 5 to load now (just is really, really slow), I just had to restart it. I figured out that Civ 6 didn't work because my computer only has 4 gigs of RAM when it needed 6 gigs.

Comment: Civ6 needs a reasonably powerful GPU, more than you usually get on a basic laptop. I think I've run it in 4GB of ram before but I have more than that now so not sure if that s a real constraint now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a bit late, but I had this same exact problem, and I fixed it with a solution in another thread. The issue seems to lie with pulseaudio. Add the following to your Civ V launch options...

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libopenal.so.1 %command%
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1335784/civ-5-crashes-on-startup